# Combine functions in ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am aiming to plot a quadratic function with s-curve in ggplot2 as in the image [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwQ7O.jpg)

This is what I get so far but the lines do not line up!My gues is it has to do with seq(0,2). Thanks so much for your comments!

```
     ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 2)), aes(x)) + 
stat_function(fun=function(x)x^2, geom="line")
      stat_function(fun = function(x) 1/(1 + exp(-x)), geom = "line")
```

Comment: you need a `+` at the end of the second line. Then the curves need scaling, and with seq(0,2) you only get half the sigmoid curve.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 2)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x)x^2, geom="line") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) 1/(1 + exp(-x)), geom = "line")
```

I think you forgot the plus sign. It works for me.